# remove non-digits except E+ and E- in string

Tags: r, regex

I have the vector `vec` that I want to convert to numeric type. Therefore I need to get rid of non-digits (including '+') first. The problem: When I exclude them also the '+' and '-' from 'E+' and 'E-' symbols are also removed.

How can I remove all non-digits except for 'E-', 'E+' and '.' from `vec`?

```
vec = c('1234', '+ 42', '1E+4', 'NR 12', '4.5E+04', '8.6E-02')
```

My approaches:

```
gsub('[^0-9E.]', '', vec) # removes '-' and '+' in 'E-' and 'E+'

gsub('[^0-9(E\\+).]', '', vec) # includes the '+' from '+ 42'
```

My desired output is:

```
c('1234', '42', '1E+4', '12', '4.5E+04', '8.6E-02')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may *extract* the numbers using the [following regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

**Details**

- `[-+]?` - either `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - an optional capturing group (add `?:` after `(` to use a non-capturing group) matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[eE]` - `e` or `E`
  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits

[R demo](https://ideone.com/q4xzSm):

```
vec <- c('1234', '+ 42', '1E+4', 'NR 12', '4.5E+04', '8.6E-02')
res <- regmatches(vec, regexpr("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?", vec))
unlist(res)
## => [1] "1234"    "42"      "1E+4"    "12"      "4.5E+04" "8.6E-02"
```

If multiple matches per item in a character vector are expected replace `regexpr` with `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your regex to check if `+` or `-` is not preceded by `E` or `e` and in that case don't remove them (using look behind and enable perl=TRUE) and otherwise, include `+` and `-` in your main character set, so they are removed in any other case with empty string. Try changing your line from this,

```
gsub('[^0-9E.]', '', vec)
```

to,

```
gsub('(?<![Ee])[+-]|[^0-9E.+-]', '', vec, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match not a digit until you encounter a number:

```
^\D+(?=(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)
```

That would match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `\D+` match 1+ times not a digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?` Match a number, or decimal number with E or e
- `)` Close positive lookahead

For example:

```
vec = c('1234', '+ 42', '1E+4', 'NR 12', '4.5E+04', '8.6E-02')
print(gsub('^\\D+(?=(?:[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)', '', vec, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "1234"    "42"      "1E+4"    "12"      "4.5E+04" "8.6E-02"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgnAHV/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/TtJ37K)

Comment: This won't work if OP has data like `NR 12 NR` which is why OP wants to replace every character from the string which aren't from this character set `[^0-9E.+-]` except if `+` and `-` are immediately following `E`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The regex starts with an anchor so that is correct, although that data is not in the example data.

Comment: Yes, your regex is correct for the data set given by OP. My point was, OP was already using a strategy which was more powerful than your regex as that would take care of the example I gave `NR 12 NR` which won't work with your regex as it assumes the non-numeric part will only appear before the numeric part.

Answer (score 1):

Well this works:

```
str_remove_all(vec,"\\D.* ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in R base and with `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\D.* ", "", vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you wanted a numeric result, but you stated your desired output as a character output (I ignored this and just went with numeric).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

vec <- c('1234', '+ 42', '1E+4', 'NR 12', '4.5E+04', '8.6E-02')

vec %>%
  str_extract_all("(\\+|\\-)*[:digit:]+(\\.)?[:digit:]*", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  apply(2, as.numeric) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V2), 0, V2)) %>%
  mutate(result = V1*10^V2)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      V1    V2    result
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1234       0  1234    
2   42       0    42    
3    1       4 10000    
4   12       0    12    
5    4.5     4 45000    
6    8.6    -2     0.086
```

... then `.$result`, of course.